# how can resize the original image in android

Tags: android, resize-image

i am working on image ,upload original image in this original image resize the small image this image saved in to database

original image --> resize it (small image )--> small image saved in to database

please forward solution

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this you'll want to play around with the Bitmap class.

It has several functions to create new bitmaps form previous ones

```
Bitmap bmp2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, true);
```

a full list can be found in the documentation :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html

Regarding the save to a database I've never done but it would depend on your server.

Comment: bmp2  bitmap convert in to bytes array (saved into byte array in db)is if possible

Comment: Not sure what your asking but if you check the doc you have getPixel(), getPixels()

Comment: i will take upload image in sdcard this image very large i can resize this image convert byte array in this byte array save in database

Comment: Then you want to use getPixels method to get a buffer which will give you a array of int. the 4 bytes of the int are the RGBA values of the pixel